# Issues with custom compare for std::priority_queue in c++98

Tags: priority-queue, c++98

I'm trying to create varaible of type 'std::priority_queue' like this:

```
struct
{
    bool operator()(std::vector<int> v1, std::vector<int> v2){return (v1[2] + v1[3]) > (v2[2] + v2[3]);};
} queueCompare;

std::priority_queue< std::vector<int>, std::vector< std::vector<int> >, queueCompare > queue;
```

But the compiler gives me this error:

```
expected a type, got `queueCompare'
```

I don't exactly understand what is wrong here. As far as I know, this should be a correct way of creating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is invalid struct definition. correctly struct definition is not `struct {...} name` but `struct name {...}` 
In addition, I recommend using const reference in the compare method to avoid unnecessary copies

```
struct queueCompare
{
    bool operator()(const std::vector<int>& v1, const std::vector<int>& v2){
        return (v1[2] + v1[3]) > (v2[2] + v2[3]);
    };
};
```

Comment: While it resolved my issue, I have to add that, as far as I'm aware, it is correct, but only when an instance of a struct is needed, not type. For example, as per std::priority_queue specification, when an interator for a data container's begin and end are provided, Compare must be an instance, as opposed to type, as is the case with the constructor used in my example. It can be seen in the code example here
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue
where the struct 'customLess' is used.

Comment: @zeregzesis Oh! anonymous struct! I learned something new. Thank you.
I don't know that you solve the problem, but the reason code like cppreferecne's example don't work in C++98 is it have not "Template Argument Type Deduction."
In lower than C++17, It must provide not only instance but also type!